# PouchDB load m4a attachment into HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, pouchdb, m4a

I have a very simple application I am making that needs to load 30 second m4a files from a couch server. I am able to receive the files but can not get them to load in a player. The files are uploaded through Fauxton and have been deleted and reuploaded to be sure the issue was not in the upload.

I have also loaded the object url into a link and tried to download the file which can not be played.

I have tried both using the source directly in the audio tag as well as adding the source tag.

I have tested the files in the audio player and they work fine locally.

I think I there is something wrong with the way I am creating the blob or url.

```
<audio controls id="mediaPlayer"></audio>

var db = new PouchDB('http://user:password@localhost:5984/music');
  db.get('9d3f17d01be8283c461eaa01940329b4', { attachments:true } ).then(function (doc){
    // Load first file
    var media = Object.values(doc._attachments)[0];
    // Get Player
    var player = document.getElementById('mediaPlayer');
    // Create blob from data - media content type is 
    var blob = new Blob([ media.data ], { type: media.content_type });
    // Create url from blob
    var afile = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // Set source and load
    player.src = afile;
    player.load();
  });
```

Comment: The code you provided seems to be missing a couple of things. Firstly, you need to specify the encoding format of the audio file in the Blob constructor. Secondly, you need to check if the browser supports the audio format before attempting to play it.

Comment: The media type is declared by the returned data.  As I stated in the message above "I have tested the files in the audio player and they work fine locally." There is something wrong in the conversion or the way I am managing the blob

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue.  This was a complete oversight on my end.  Fauxton uploads all attachments as Base64 not blobs.  I had to simply decode the data before converting it to a blob. I am using node so I used buffer to decode the string before creating the blob.

If you are using raw vanilla js you should be able to use `atob(media.data)` in place of the buffer, but I did not test it.

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

var db = new PouchDB('http://user:password@localhost:5984/music');
db.get('9d3f17d01be8283c461eaa01940329b4', { attachments:true } ).then(function (doc){
    // Load first file
    var media = Object.values(doc._attachments)[0];
    // Get Player
    var player = document.getElementById('mediaPlayer');
    // Remove Encoding
    var raw = Buffer.from(media.data, 'base64');
    // Create blob from data
    var blob = new Blob([ raw ], { type: media.content_type });
    // Create url from blob
    var afile = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // Set source and load
    player.src = afile;
    player.load();
});
```